# Aumentar Velocidade de loop de Espirógrafos no turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7

Utilizando estas referências: [Spirograph Patterns](http://www.eddaardvark.co.uk/python_patterns/spirograph.html) e [python 3.4 spirograph error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770300/python-3-4-spirograph-error) o seguinte código foi criado:

### Código

```
import turtle
import math
import random

def Xcord(R,r,p,t):
    return (R-r) * math.cos(t) - (r+p) * math.cos((R-r)//r*t)

def Ycord (R,r,p,t):
    return (R-r) * math.sin(t) - (r+p) * math.sin((R-r)//r*t)

def t_iter(R,r,p):
    t=0
    turtle.up()
    Xcord(R,r,p,t)
    Ycord(R,r,p,t)
    while t < 2*math.pi:
        t+=0.01
        turtle.goto(Xcord(R,r,p,t),Ycord(R,r,p,t))
        random_hex = random_color()
        turtle.color(random_hex)
        turtle.pencolor(random_hex)
        turtle.down()
    return float(Xcord(R,r,p,t))
    return float(Ycord(R,r,p,t))

def p_iter(count, p_iter_length):
        return 10.0 + (count*p_iter_length)

def random_color():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0, 255)
    return('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(), r(), r()))

def main():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("black")
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.shape("turtle")
    R=100
    r=4
    count=0
    p = 10.0
    while p <=100.0:
        p = p_iter(count, 10.0)
        t_iter(R,r,p)
        Xcord(R,r,p,t_iter(R,r,p))
        Ycord(R,r,p,t_iter(R,r,p))
        count+=1
    window.exitonclick()

main()
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/CandidMajorGreyware)</sup>

### Problema

**Como Aumentar a Velocidade de um programa de Espirógrafo no turtle?**

Aumentando o valor do loop de `t` (ex.: de 0.01 para 0.2), o espirógrafo perde forma e a maior velocidade do turtle é `turtle.speed(0)`.

O espirógrafo da várias voltas extras em linhas já feitas antes de sair do loop, para otimizar haveria a possibilidade de sair do loop após terminar uma volta no espirógrafo. Mas não consegui encontrar uma maneira de realizar isto.

**Como sair do loop após uma volta no espirógrafo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como Aumentar a Velocidade de um programa de Espirógrafo no turtle?

A Turtle é lenta - mas  a maior lentidão vem realmente do fato de que ela atualiza a tela após cada passo, por menor que seja, por padrão.
Além do speed(0), você pode chamar o método `turtle.tracer` que aceita dois parâmetros: a cada quantos "passos" ele vai de fato atualizar a tela, e quanto esperar entre cada atualização.  Só isso já deixa seu programa rápido o suficiente para você poder experimentar mais - logo abaixo da linha

```
window = turtle.Screen()
```

Ponha

```
turtle.tracer(100,0)
```

Vocẽ também pode querer esconder a tartaruga - não vejo muito sentido em mostrar a figura em si nesse programa, em que o mais importante é o desenho, e não entender "pra que lado a tartaruga está indo". Em vez de chamar `turtle.shape(...)`, experimente chamar `turtle.hideturtle()`.

Agora, há alguns erros conceituais no seu programa  - em particular as funções XCoord e Ycoord são chamadas várias vezes, calculam seus valores e nada é feito com o valor de retorno das mesmas, - somente a chamada as mesmas como parâmetros ao `turtle.goto`  e na linha de return tem algum efeito.

Essas funções não são tão complexas a ponto das chamadas redundantes, uma vez pra cada passo - mas você pode simplesmente guardar os valores delas em variáveis locais, em vez de chama-las de novo cada vez que precisa dos valores. Da mesma forma dois comandos `return` dentro de uma função não fazem nada: apenas o primeiro é executado, e a função é interrompida.

> Como sair do loop?

Coloquei essa pergunta a mais por que é mais simples de fazer: a chamada `window.exitonclick()` é legal, mas ela para o seu programa - por isso não pode ser feita dentro do loop. Como, me parece, o mais importante é você poder sair quando o desenho estiver completo para rodar o programa com outros parâmetros, é possível chegar as ligações do tkinter "por dentro" do turtle, e conectar diretamente um click com o final do programa.

Dentro da sua função main, antes do `while` coloque essas três linhas:

```
canvas = window.getcanvas()
root = canvas._nametowidget(canvas.winfo_parent())
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: root.destroy())
```

pronto - adicionamos um handler para o evento de clicar o botão-1 mesmo
enquanto o desenho está sendo feito.  O módulo turtle tem o seu método "onclick" também - mas por algum motivo ele não funciona enquanto o desenho está sendo feito.

Perceba que com o método acima, é possível usar a janela "root" para extender sua aplicação com turtle para uma aplicação tkinter normal - você pode adicionar caixas de entrada (`tkinter.Entry`) e botões para mudar parâmetros da sua turtle dentro da própria janela - sem precisar sair do programa para reconfigurar parâmetros de desenho.

> Como sair do loop após uma volta no espirógrafo?

Não detectei o loop re-desenhando voltas ja completas no espirógrafo. A forma correta é justamente comparar o valor de "t" com 2 * pi - ou se você tiver um divisor de "t" dentro das funções seno e co-seno, se preocupar que o valor passado pra as mesmas seja no máximo 2 * pi. Seu código já faz isso.

Como eu limpei as chamadas a mais pras funções XCoord, e coloquei as duas ou três coisas a mais, coloco o programa inteiro de volta:

```
import turtle
import math
import random

def Xcord(R,r,p,t):
    return (R-r) * math.cos(t) - (r+p) * math.cos((R-r)//r*t)

def Ycord (R,r,p,t):
    return (R-r) * math.sin(t) - (r+p) * math.sin((R-r)//r*t)

def t_iter(R,r,p):
    t=0
    turtle.up()
    while t < 2*math.pi:
        t+=0.01
        x = Xcord(R,r,p,t)
        y = Ycord(R,r,p,t)
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        random_hex = random_color()
        turtle.color(random_hex)
        turtle.pencolor(random_hex)
        turtle.down()


def p_iter(count, p_iter_length):
        return 10.0 + (count*p_iter_length)

def random_color():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0, 255)
    return('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(), r(), r()))

def main():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    turtle.tracer(100,0)

    canvas = window.getcanvas()
    root = canvas._nametowidget(canvas.winfo_parent())
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: root.destroy())

    window.bgcolor("black")
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    R=100
    r=4
    count=0
    p = 10.0
    while p <=100.0:
        p = p_iter(count, 10.0)
        t_iter(R,r,p)
        count+=1
    window.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: Aprendi bastante com estas alterações, muito detalhada =]. E sobre `Como sair do loop após uma volta no espirógrafo?`, se você observar no Repl.it da pergunta. Ele realmente sobrescreve o que já foi desenhado, pelo menos aparentemente. Mas com essas otimizações, mesmo que passe não será muito visível. Poderei testar mais o turtle!